# Add search path to VS Code workspace

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, search, path

Thanks for checking out this post! I'm trying out VS Code for Python having been using VS Studio for a while (the intellisense is really bad, which is why I am looking to change IDE). I can't seem to find the way you add a search path. In VS Studio I would add 'src' to my Search Paths which would make importing modules within 'src' clean.

How can I add my 'src' file to the search path in VS Code?

Thanks for you time looking into this!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Open [Settings.json](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings#_creating-user-and-workspace-settings), add the following configurations:

```
"python.analysis.autoSearchPaths": true,  //Automatically add common search paths like 'src'.
"python.analysis.extraPaths": [
     //Additional import search resolution paths
    "folderA",
]
```

Comment: Thanks for this! I managed to do this by adding the following to launch.json

"env": {
                "PYTHONPATH": "${workspaceRoot};src"
            }

Comment: hi, why it didn't work for me?

settings.json:

{
    "python.linting.enabled": false,


    "python.analysis.autoSearchPaths": true 
    "python.analysis.extraPaths": [
        //Additional import search resolution paths
        "/home/smsa/.local/share/virtualenvs/romina-platform-xL2V2Bio",
    
    ]

}