# Set VS Code Environment to include Python Module

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

[image]

When I run this Python code in the context of Houdini, the code properly pulls in the FilePathUtils class. However, VS Code isn't offering any nice IDE support because it apparently isn't aware of the specific `pipe` module that I'm using.

Is there a way I can point the editor to this module so that I can get proper IDE support of the classes that I pull in this way?

Comment:  Please post code, errors, sample data or textual output here as plain-text, not as images that can be hard to read, can’t be copy-pasted to help test code or use in answers, and are barrier to those who depend on screen readers or translation tools. You can edit your question to add the code in the body of your question. For easy formatting use the `{}` button to mark blocks of code, or indent with four spaces for the same effect. The contents of a **screenshot can’t be searched, run as code, or easily copied and edited to create a solution.**

Comment: You'll need to set up VS Code to have the same module search paths as Houdini, which could be quite a project.

Comment: Why not create a new virtual environment and then install all of the modules you need into that virtual environment.  Or set the `PYTHONPATH` environment variable to include the path to that pipe module if its not installed in a standard location.

Comment: You can try updating VS Code's search paths to explicitly specify where to find your packages: https://stackoverflow.com/q/69410170/2745495

Comment: Does this answer your question? ['Import "Path.to.own.script" could not be resolved Pylance (reportMissingImports)' in VS Code using Python 3.x on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65252074/import-path-to-own-script-could-not-be-resolved-pylance-reportmissingimports)

Comment: May I know what's going on with the problem? If it has been solved, can you change the status of the answer to help more people with similar problems.

Answer (score 1):

Use this setting to add the path to a specific module：

```json
    "python.analysis.extraPaths": [
        "/home/flo/happyspace/src/fmp_tracepen_node/src"
    ],
```